# Stubbing built-in nodejs modules in Webpack

Tags: webpack, server-side-rendering, v8, webpack-4, serverside-javascript

I'm running some nodejs code via server side rendering. Specifically, I'm using the [mini_racer](https://github.com/rubyjs/mini_racer) gem for Ruby.
I'm using webpack to bundle my Javascript files.
I'm running into an issue where one my dependencies makes use of built-in nodejs modules (e.g., http, events, fs, etc).

When I'm running it in a V8 environment, those modules do not exist (i.e., using `require` will not work because that function is undefined).

**Is there a way I can just stub those modules via webpack? or some other Javascript solution if that doesn't work.** Perhaps using some built-in webpack property or a plugin?

Ultimately, I don't need those modules and would like to bypass via some stub, but I have no control the 3rd party dependency that requires them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately there is a way to do this in the webpack config:

```js
{
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
      net: false,
      tls: false,
    },
    alias: {
      stream: 'stream-browserify',
      zlib: 'browserify-zlib',
    }
  }
}
```

Fallback will simply add empty stubs to the modules, while alias will supplement with another module made for the browser.

This is for webpack 5, before with version 4 you could simply do:

```js
{
  node: {
    fs: false
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this would solve my problem @matthiasgiger. 
Reading the [docs](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/node/), it seems like using the 'false' option would just make the importing fail and break the dependency. Instead I'd rather stub this out with custom code if possible (more akin to the alias option you gave).
I am using webpack 4 and also setting `target: node` (otherwise it will run the browser variant of my dependency and try using the document). Is this possible in webpack 4?

Comment: also `require` itself is not defined because although this is nodejs, I'm running in a v8 environment where built in modules are not defined.

Comment: The alias option also works in webpack 4. http and fs modules only make sense in node and therefore cannot be polyfilled for the browser or the MiniRacer engine. It would probably be possible to provide those modules natively on the side of the MiniRacer engine but I doubt that's going to happen anytime soon. Using node is probably the only option to achieve what you're trying to do.